# systemd: allow override of After= directive

Tags: systemd, services, daemon

I have two services, service Init and service Daemon.

Service Init does system setup and is often used to setup a configuration file for service Daemon (ie, `echo "MY_ENV_VAR=true" >> /etc/daemon/daemon.config`)

For this reason, we have service Daemon start after Init using `After=Init.service` in the daemon.service file.

Some users, however, will want to start or restart the Daemon service within their Init service. Is there a way that we can have the "After" directive while also allowing for it to be overridden?

ie, we want to use After=, but we want it to be a soft dependency.

Comment: FYI, there's ExecStartPre, if you don't need a full-fledged *service unit* for the "Init" portion...

Comment: It’s hard to tell from your description, but systemd unit overrides may meet your requirements — see [example 2 here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Examples).

Comment: @JeffSchaller unfortunately that's not an option, the Init service is not controllable by us.

Comment: @StephenKitt in this case the user would need to copy and create their own unit file, which is what we're currently recommending but were hoping to avoid.

Comment: @Cameron they don’t need to copy the unit file, they can create an override with only the section and `After` line, using `systemctl edit`.

Comment: @StephenKitt from the link you posted: "Dependencies (After=, etc.) cannot be reset to an empty list, so dependencies can only be added in drop-ins. If you want to remove dependencies, you have to override the entire unit."

my understanding of this is that the user would need to override the entire unit, which is what we are hoping to avoid.

Comment: @Cameron ah yes, sorry, I missed that part.